# Using Android Studio Android app Working Google plus on device but when downloaded from play store Not Work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-plus-signin

When I build and deploy this app on my device via USB using Android Stdio, it works as expected. But, when, I upload and download this app from play store, Google+ login not working, It showing a blank screen.

Comment: Using our magical abilities we have detected the the problem. Please give us your credit card info and we'll give you the solution. Seriously though, we really have no idea. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Basically this error will be occured when your application SHA key has been not matched with SHA key of google console.This key will be different from release and debug environment. Whenever you will changing development machine/computer this key will be changing. You just need to update SHA key in google console using this link [https://console.developers.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyQzl.png) . For more details image attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you registered new cliend ID (OAuth) in developers console with your new certificate fingerprint (SHA1)?

(maybe this helps: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)